# Create MVC pattern in Express and substitute routes folder with controllers folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller

New to Express. Want to implement an MVC pattern in Express and substitute routes folder with controller folder. I found this code, which actually works, but I don't really understand what it does:

```
var fs = require('file-system');    

fs.readdirSync('controllers').forEach(function (file) {
      if(file.substr(-3) == '.js') {
        const route = require('./controllers/' + file);
        route.controller(app);
      }
    })
```

The readdirSync reads the content of the folder 'controllers' and for each file it founds it does something that I don't understand:

**if(file.substr(-3) == '.js')** //checks if the end of the file is .js but why?

**const route = require('./controllers/' + file);** //don't understand this

**route.controller(app);** //don't understand this

Could you please help with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you follow comes from [this blog entry](http://timstermatic.github.io/blog/2013/08/17/a-simple-mvc-framework-with-node-and-express/) by Tim Roberts. The example controller demonstrates what is it all about:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Video = require('../models/user');

module.exports.controller = function(app) {

  app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
      // any logic goes here
      res.render('users/signup')
  });

  app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
      // any logic goes here
      res.render('users/login')
  });
}
```

If you save this example controller in the `controllers` folder under `whatever.js`, all it does it exports a function, `controller`, that takes the express app as an argument and adds a couple of custom routes to the app.

Then, the main module scans all such files under the `controllers` folder and first uses the `require` function to load the module:

```
const route = require('./controllers/' + file);
```

After above line, the `route` contains a reference to the module that contains this `controller` function.

This

```
route.controller(app);
```

just calls the function exported from the module, passing the global `app` as an argument.

This way you can easily extend your app just by creating separate `.js` modules under `controllers` folder, that follow the same convention (export the `controller` function).